# Why does youtube player(and maybe others too) overlaps floating div?

Tags: youtube, flash

How do I prevent it from coming to the front. Flowplayer doesn't behave this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash elements are, by default, on top of everything.  See [this article](http://fruitnotes.com/blogs/Flash_Object_And_Z-Index_How_To_Make_Them_Play_Nicely_Together_759) for a tutorial on how to counter-act that behavior.